# reCaptcha works locally but not on PythonAnywhere

Tags: recaptcha, pythonanywhere

Locally on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ reCaptcha works as expected.
When deployed to PythonAnywhere ("production") on the form it is supposed to work, I get only "Verify" (the label) but nothing else.

I have used to keys from Google in db.py as:
from gluon.tools import Recaptcha
`auth.settings.captcha = Recaptcha(request,
    '6LeHlgMTAAAAAPMaNZSNaaYabmbr8amc6BzjAjsu', '6LeHlgMTAAAAAKCaa8nUQsmDPjpAAh_CIR40o7G')`

I have added the script from Google in layout.html
And another script from Google at the end of the form where reCaptcha is supposed to be.

I know that locally reCaptcha is not really checking the public/private keys, and that may explain why it works locally, but still - what am I doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Does the recaptcha library access any external servers from the server side?  If you have a free PythonAnywhere account, it might be trying to access a server that's not on the whitelist (https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).  We (the PythonAnywhere devs) can whitelist a site if it has a public API (which I'm sure will be the case for recaptcha) -- just let us know the hostname via a "Send feedback" message on the PythonAnywhere site.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...So the issue was on PythonAnywhere side.
Once they took care of the whitelist - reCaptcha works as expected from the website hosted at PythonAnywhere.
And....this feature is now also part of the free option (it used to be available only for paid sites).
Thanks Giles and Conrad !

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start) for reCaptcha, you will see that

1. you need to set up an API key pair specifically for your pythonanywhere site, and
2. the verification process involves getting your webapp to talk to the google reCAPTCHA server to verify.

This second part means that you will have to get a paying account for this to work as PythonAnywhere restricts external internet access to whitelisted sites only.

Comment: Thanks Giles and Conrad. I will get a paid account with PythonAnywhere and will let you guys know if I still face any obstacles with reCaptcha integration with Web2Py.

Comment: Hi Toren, just to let you know, after seeing your question, we literally just added reCaptcha to our whitelist seconds ago! So you actually don't need to upgrade to a paid account yet... (but it would be nice! :p)